# How do you reset mocks between tests using @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)?

Tags: mocking, mockito, junit5

I'm writing some service tests with mockito and JUnit 5.  What is the proper way to reset my mocks after each test when applying the @ExtendWith annotation?  I have a basic structure

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class MyServiceTest {

  @Mock private MyRepo myRepo;

  @InjectMocks private MyService myService;

    ...

  @Test
  public void testSave() {
    given(myRepo.find(val)).willReturn(myData);
    ...
  }

}
```

I'm finding between tests the mocks are retaining their values.

Comment: Can you give an example where you are seeing retained values? JUnit should create a new test class instance for each test method - and I am observing this behaviour on my PC.